# dojo1.8 - Not sure how to read the selected value and post to php file, using dojo/request

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, dojo

Hi I have problem getting the value of select node posted and get nothing.
I am using dojo/request. And the getuser1.php at the server is working when I tested with simple ajax file.

At the request line, the values for data may not be correct

Please advise... Thanks

Following are two scripts:-
main.php file -

```
require(["dojo/parser", "dojo/ready","dijit/form/Select",
         "dojo/request","dojo/on","dojo/domReady!"],
function(parser, ready, Select, request, on){

    ready(function(){   

        console.debug('Rendering...');
        var selectX = new Select({
            name:'select_test',
            options:[
                {label:"<span class='NotinUse'><b>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp. . .</b></span>", value:'0', selected:true},
                {label:"<span class='inUse'><b>&nbsp&nbspPeter Griffin</b></span>", value:'1'},
                {label:"<span class='inUse'><b>&nbsp&nbspLois Griffin</b></span>", value:'2'},
                {label:"<span class='inUse'><b>&nbsp&nbspJoseph Swanson</b></span>", value:'3'},
                {label:"<span class='inUse'><b>&nbsp&nbspGlenn Quagmire</b></span>", value:'4'},
            ], 
            style:{width:'150px'}
        },"select");

        on(formNode2, 'Change', function(evt){
            evt.stopPropagation();
            evt.preventDefault();

            request.post('getuser1.php',{   
                data:{select_test:this.value},
                timeout:2000
            }).then(function(response){
                dom.byId('line2').innerHTML=response;
            });
        });
    });
});
```

getuser1.php file:-

```
<?php 
$q=$_GET["q"];

$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("ajax_demo", $con);


$sql="SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = $q";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

// use stored function to return one result instead later. Write here after stored     procedure has been stored. 

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th width=100>Firstname</th>
<th width=100>Lastname</th>
<th width=100>Age</th>
<th width=100>Height</th>
<th width=100>Hometown</th>
<th width=100>Job</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['FirstName'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['LastName'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Age'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Height'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Hometown'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Job'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
    echo "</table>";

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember to use your browser's error console when developing, it will often notify you of simple typos etc in your code.

In this case, there are a few things wrong. It seems you've mixed up `selectX` and `formNode2`. It should presumably be:

```
on(selectX, 'Change', function(evt){
```

Now, if you get this to work, you'll notice that when you change `selectX`'s value, you'll get an error in your console:

```
evt.stopPropagation is not a function
```

This is because the evt argument is not actually an event object here. From select elements, you only get the new value, *not* the event. Change it to something like this, and you should see what I mean in the console:

```
on(selectX, 'Change', function( newValue ){
    console.debug('The new value is', newValue);
    //evt.stopPropagation();
    //evt.preventDefault();
```

I made a few changes to make it work in jsfiddle, but it should give you an idea: http://fiddle.jshell.net/AmxKv/

Comment: Hi Thanks  However, I am not able to produce output. If I were not to use the switch, I can just insert "data:{q:2}" as you can see "$q=$_GET["q"];" in getuser1.php. So what could be wrong? Please advise. Thanks in advance

Comment: @user1739825 You need to determine whether your PHP script or Javascript is the problem. 1) Does the Javascript make a request to the server (check with firebug)? 2) What is the response from the server when this happens (check with firebug)? 3) Is the `function(response) {...}` function called? (put a console.debug statement in there and check with firebug.) Your question is very broad - like I've pointed out, there are several errors in the code you've pasted. You need to make an effort to pinpoint the problem yourself.

Comment: If I input "data('q':2)" with console.debug(responses), the output  is:- <table border='1'>
<tr>
<th width=100>Firstname</th>
<th width=100>Lastname</th>
<th width=100>Age</th>
<th width=100>Height</th>
<th width=100>Hometown</th>
<th width=100>Job</th>
</tr></table>  I can see that "request.post" is able to call getuser1.php but it seems that PHP script cannot be processed. And I noticed "Post" in main.php and "Get" in getuser1.php. I change to GET in both files. and it still does not work